# HttpClient pattern with dynamic username and password

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

We have one single endpoint that dispatches requests to many endpoints with varying credentials and auth type (basic and digest auth; and username/password combinations). The credentials are given in the incoming request. How can I wire up HttpClient in such a way that it is reused as much as possible? In particular I am worried about socket exhaustion which is frequently mentioned when not reusing HttpClient instances properly. Additionally, I would prefer to have good inversion of control and factories for proper unit testing.

Naively one could do the following per request:

```cs
using var messageHandler = new HttpClientHandler() {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
};
using var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
```

Using .NET Core 3.1.

`IHttpClientFactory` does not have means to inject `HttpMessageHandler` implementations dynamically. It picks the ones that you configure in the IOC wiring, or just the default `HttpClientHandler`.

I have moved above code to a factory:

```cs
public class AuthenticatedHttpClientFactory : IAuthenticatedHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient GetClient(string username, string password)
    {
        var messageHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
        };
        var client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
        return client;
    }
}
```

In the consumer code I dispose the provided `HttpClient`, but do I need to explicitly dispose the `HttpMessageHandler`? Is it automatically done when disposing the HttpClient? Or how do I do that?

Comment: It sounds like it would be better to authenticate the individual requests rather than configure the whole`HttpClient` / handler to do it. That way you'll probably end up with only a single client being needed.

Comment: Is this going to be in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: ASP.NET Core with .NET Core 3.1. @sellotape; indeed, I found this: https://github.com/oliver-wood/httpclient-digest-net-standard. But I would like to reuse the auth code that is already in the SDK. The SDK is smart and tries basic first and then responds with digest if required.